# Converting Spidertracks GPS flight tracks into shapefile or kml?

Tags: shapefile, kml, convert

I have some data that will be comming to me from helicopter flights and was recorded with [Spidertracks](http://www.spidertracks.com/) software. Does anyone know how to convert flight tracks from 'Spidertracks' gps flight tracks into shapefile or kml? What is the raw spidertracks gps format? I am trying to learn before I recieve the data and I'm not 100% sure what format I will be recieving.

Comment: https://app.spidertracks.com/Home.mvc/Faqs#q3

Comment: Definately good info there. Looks like it may depend on the client's account & abilites with the Spidertracks interface(?). The client will be providing me with the data so hopefully there will be little-to-no problems.

Comment: You can get KML directly out of the Fleetpro or Aviator products

Comment: Great, when I'm in contact with the client I can inform if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data can be pulled in a live kml feed or XML too.

We have great support guys that will no doubt be able to help you out too.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for weighing in, Luke, and welcome to our site! Please feel free to add any identifying/contact information you like to your *user profile.* It is a Stack Exchange policy not to include such info within questions or answers, though.

Comment: I was able to export a csv file directly from spidertracks online and then convert to xls. I used the xls to display and export the points and then used the Point to Line conversion tool designating each Line based on the Date field. The end result showed the flight lines for each day. Its a bit of a process, however it resulted in what I needed.